# Ubuntu 13.10 AMD/ATI proprietary driver slow boot time, lengthy login/logout delays

Tags: unity, ati, 13.10, proprietary, catalyst

Ubuntu 13.10 is causing me major headaches with my AMD/ATI HD 5770 GPU. Below is a list of problems I am currently encountering.

1) The boot time is extended by at least 25s after installing catalyst 13.11 beta. Using open source radeon drivers, my boot time till the login screen is ~10s. With catalyst 13.11 beta installed, the boot time increases to ~35s. This was not the case in Ubuntu 13.04, 12.10 or 12.04. I have done the driver installation manually (instructions from wiki.cchtml.com) and using software center and there is no difference. I have not tried the catalyst 13.8 beta driver.

2) The delay between logging in and unity being displayed is ~10-15s for BOTH open source and proprietary drivers. During the delay, it's just a black screen. Whenever I logout, there is again a ~10-15s delay with the login screen appearing stuck before lightdm allows me to enter my password again. This is ridiculous!

Yes, I could stick with open source radeon drivers but I would like to install Steam and play my Valve collection on the machine. Is anybody else encountering similar issues?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use hibernation try to edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and put `#` in front of

```
RESUME=XXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 13.10 64bits, use the latest beta driver : http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amd-catalyst-13.11-betav1-linux-x86.x86_64.zip

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction. I have since installed the beta 13.11 driver. The black screen issue is now gone but the noticeable delay in bootup and login is still there.

Comment: I had the exact same problem - black screen on login. i can confirm that the beta drivers fix the issue. To save a complete re-install, you can use a boot disk, copy the unzipped file onto the hd, make it executable, then boot back using the hd, at the blank screen use ctrl+alc+f2, then cd to the file, and ./ run it. you may need to use sudo nautilus to mount the hd in write mode to copy the file over. -ralph

Comment: I have nvidia graphics card and am facing the delay mentioned in point 3 ever since i upgraded to 13.10. Any help? or would you suggest I open a different quest?